# background image problem

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i have an image sized 768X1024 and when i set the background image to a view,  at the bottom it displays the white color (20pixel).Eventhough I incereses the image size 768X1044 it repeats the same.Please help me.

Comment: what's do you get for [theImage position];?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the position is set to `CGPointMake(0,0)`, with

```
[theImage setPosition:CGPointMake(0,0)];
```

It's probably just positioned up by 20 pixels.